# Multiline TextBox multiple newline

Tags: asp.net, html, textbox, multiline

I set a value for a `Multiline Textbox` like this.

```
textBox1.Text = "Line1\r\n\r\nLine2";
```

But, only one line space in output.

When I read the value of textbox, I read `"Line1\r\nLine2"`;

Why does ASP.NET not support more then one lineline character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. If I add one Environment.Newline I get one new line in the textbox. But if I add two Environment.Newline I get one new line.
In my web app I use a whitespace modul that removes all unnecessary white spaces. If i disable this module I get two new lines in my textbox. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 51):

You need to set the textbox to be multiline, this can be done two ways:

**In the control:**

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="MyBox" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" />
```

**Code Behind:**

```
MyBox.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
MyBox.Rows = 10;
```

This will render as a `<textarea>`

Comment: I set it to multiline. But, I cannot set programatically, multiple line space to the textbox.

Answer (score 17):

```
textBox1.Text = "Line1" + Environment.NewLine + "Line2";
```

Also the markup needs to include TextMode="MultiLine" (otherwise it shows text as one line)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="multitxt" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: which broswer are you using, i checked this in IE7 and FF works perfect. I hope you have typed the above thing properly !

Comment: I check this with IE 8 and Google Chrome. Same result.

Comment: The is no update panel. But, when I put the textbox in updatePanel and set the value of textbox when a submit button click, TextBox set correctly. You can try this on your development environment. Strange situation, maybe a bug.

Comment: Actually, when page is postback, there is no problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one

> textBox1.Text = "Line1" + Environment.NewLine + "Line2";

Working fine for me...

Comment: Yo can use multiple **Environment.NewLine**

Comment: IE renders just one new line. try it.

Comment: I'm using  


`txtMultiline.Text = "Line1" + Environment.NewLine + "Line2" + Environment.NewLine + "Line3";`
  


and its working fine in all browsers

Comment: Only one Environment.NewLine is OK, but multiple Environment.NewLine not working. For example; txtMultiline.Text = "Line1" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Line2";

Comment: I'm using `txtMultiline.Text = "Line1" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Line2" + Environment.NewLine + "Line3";` and its working fine

Answer (score 2):

When page IsPostback, the following code work correctly. But when page first loading, there is not multiple newline in the textarea. Bug

```
textBox1.Text = "Line1\r\n\r\n\r\nLine2";
```

Answer (score 0):

While dragging the TextBox it self Press F4 for Properties and under the Textmode set to Multiline, The representation of multiline to a text box is it can be sizable at 6 sides. And no need to include any **newline** characters for getting multiline. May be you set it multiline but you dint increased the size of the Textbox at design time.

Comment: textBox1.Text = "Line1\r\n\r\nLine2";

Only, one line space occured.

Comment: Do, you have increased the Size of the Textbox at design time.

Comment: No, chance at all @user741356, i am sure that if you give "\r\r" between Line1 and Line2 the texts will get change of gaps between them as indicated to that Code.

Comment: sorry, by mistake i had given, thats "\r\n" Ok. It will keep the gap as the both increases their number of occurence between the Texts.

Answer (score 0):

`textBox1.Text = "Line1\r\r\Line2";` 
 Solved the problem.