# Textbox instead of messagebox to this code

Tags: textbox, mac-address

I would like to know how can I add a Textbox that displays the MAC Addresses by a new line for each address/line.

So it would look something like this:

## 1: 00:DC:FF:AE:BC:40

## 2: 00:0C:F6:DE:BA:30

```
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
string MACAddress = "";
foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
{
  if (mo["MacAddress"] != null)
  {
    MACAddress = mo["MacAddress"].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(MACAddress);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of newline characters (\n) and setting the textbox to multiline mode.  See [Multiline TextBox multiple newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909864/multiline-textbox-multiple-newline) for more info.