# C#, How to split strings to new line during foreach loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

Using Powershell Object and running foreach loop to get the results,

I got 2 correct IP Address results 144.68.205.19 and 144.68.205.22 but it printed in 1 line,

```
144.68.205.19144.68.205.22
```

Which it was suppose to be split new line like this,

```
144.68.205.19
144.68.205.22
```

Please advise, here a C# codes,

```
// Powershell
            Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runSpace.Open();
            Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline();

            Command invokeScript = new Command("Invoke-Command");
            RunspaceInvoke invoke = new RunspaceInvoke();

            // invoke-command -computername compName -scriptblock { get-process }

            ScriptBlock sb = invoke.Invoke("{"+ PowerShellCodeBox.Text +"}")[0].BaseObject as ScriptBlock;
            invokeScript.Parameters.Add("scriptBlock", sb);
            invokeScript.Parameters.Add("computername", TextBoxServer.Text);

    string str = "";

    pipeline.Commands.Add(invokeScript);
    Collection<PSObject> output = pipeline.Invoke();
    foreach (PSObject psObject in output)
    {

        str = str + psObject;
    }

    if (str == ""){
        str = "Error";

        ResultBox.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF0000");
    }

    ResultBox.Text = str;
```

Comment: P.s.w.g is correct.  With this data you have no idea where the first IP ends and the second one starts.

Comment: If you are sure that there will always be a `144`, split the string at `144` and prefix the resulting string with it.

Comment: No, `str = str + psObject;` won't split as a newline, you append them. Use an array or a list to store them, or append a newline delimiter if you still want that as only one string.

Comment: It is `144.68.205.19` and `144.68.205.22`. They just put it together in 1 line. I just want to to put new line instead of putting together.

Comment: is psObject the entire IP Address?  if so just add \r\n:   str = str + psObject +"\r\n";

Comment: Why was the PowerShell tag removed?  Seems to me its pretty darn relevant.

Comment: psObject should be entire IP Address

Comment: I think this issue has more to do with how to get an ASP TextBox control to show multiple lines.  See this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909864/multiline-textbox-multiple-newline  There's an answer at the very bottom.

Comment: I can see that but that only if they only display 2 results. My results is vary which it could be 4, 7, 1, or 10 results...

Comment: Rather than append "\r\n", does it work if you use `str += psObject + "\r\r";`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just insert a new line as you're building up `str`:

```
foreach (PSObject psObject in output)
{
    str += "\n" + psObject;
}
```

Or use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string str = String.Join("\n", output);
```

Comment: It doesn't split at all

Comment: What type is `ResultBox`?

Comment: `ResultBox` is a asp Textbox with `Textmode="MultiLine"`

Comment: My apologies. The reason it doesn't work is because I didn't rebuild the solution and it haven't updated for long time. I created a new file, copied the code then use your example and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For starters, if you're planning on building a string in a loop, look at using [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Secondly, you're never appending a new line in there, but that's easily solved (using a native method of stringbuilder, too!)

```
pipeline.Commands.Add(invokeScript);
Collection<PSObject> output = pipeline.Invoke();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (PSObject psObject in output)
{
    sb.AppendLine(psObject.ToString());
}
```