# New Line In TextArea from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on an ASP.NET application. Text is taken from a database where line breaks are stored as `'\r\n'` and I'm putting the text into a TextBox with MultiLine enabled.
However, I can't seem to get a line break into the TextBox

```
string description = description.Replace("\\r\\n", "<br/>");
lblDescriptionV.Text = description;
```

I've tried replacing the line break with: `<br/>` , `&#13;&#10;`, `&#10;` but the value is just printed into the texbox. 
So it'll read: `"Line 1<br/>line 2"`.

Comment: `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: Looks like you could check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909864/multiline-textbox-multiple-newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtArea" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" />
```

code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtArea.Text = "Hello\nThere\nFriend";
}
```

Therefore you require the following:

```
string description = "Hello\\r\\nThere\\r\\nFriend";
description = description.Replace("\\r\\n", "\n");
```

*Note: You cannot enter breaks into a label (lblDescriptionV)*

Comment: Thanks. A bit odd how everywhere I looked said replace '\n' with this and that. But it works now :)

PS. lblDescriptionV is actually a textarea - a little mistake with my naming convention there...

Answer (score 5):

Replace it with `Environment.NewLine`